# Set node view count manually

Tags: nodes

This might be not the smartest way to do, but is it possible to set the node view count per node manually?

I'm manually exporting my nodes to another Drupal without using modules; basically, I'm copy-pasting everything since there are things that are changed. The only thing that bothers me is that the number of times a node has been  viewed will be lost.

Is there a way to manually change the number of times a node has been viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to change this would be by editing each record in your database using a tool such as PHPmyAdmin. Once you have migrated to the new website, and enabled the Statistics module you will see the column added in your database table.

Hope it all goes well.

Chandeep

Comment: That is actually a good idea, didn't think of that!

Comment: Yes it's easy to get stuck in the world of Drupal and it's modules and completely forget about the database being helpful :)